# Can't authenticate to YouTube Data API anymore

Tags: youtube-data-api

We have two sites setup using the same API Key for uploading videos, one is the public server, another is on my local machine.

Even though they both use exactly the same credentials, the one on the public server is not working anymore (we're using https://github.com/laplacesdemon/django-youtube), throwing an error that credentials are incorrect.

Weirdly, I don't know where can be the problem.

There was one thing on our server, though, we changed the location so the IP address has changed.

Might it be this?

The IP list on the Server Key settings on Google Console is empty, and on the APIs requests graph I can see requests but can't find any log associated with them or something like this to see what's wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Anyway, I guess the access is somehow blocked and there is no way to unblock it.

If anyone experiencing same issue, just create a new YouTube account! The only way of solving it, apparently.